# How to accept JSON and XML both in Web API post method in .Net 5

Tags: .net, api, .net-core, .net-5, webapi

I have an API method that has a FromBody Model and it's working properly with JSON data as input but when I use XML as an input parameter, it throws an error. I tried using XMLserialiser in the startup file.

```
services.AddControllers(options => 
    { 
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    })
```

Nothing worked.

```
 [HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Model model)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For any one still trying to figure this out you can take a look here as it solved my own issue [Combine Json and Xml](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/combine-xml-and-json-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core-web-api/).
Following that simple tutorial i was able to post either content type as Json or xml.